# debug: jquery fails silently, how to prevent it

Tags: jquery, debugging

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Patterns for avoiding jQuery silent fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3047932/patterns-for-avoiding-jquery-silent-fails)

how to force jquery to exit WITH error instead of failing silently (in firebug console i see nothing and i don't know, what was wrong)

Comment: Please provide the code that is failing silently.

Comment: Note that `$("random meaningless stuff")` is **not** considered an error or "failure".

Comment: but if you call a function on it, all script stopped without any error notices. sometimes it would be convienient to be able to see what happened

Comment: @Pointy I believe the point is the author considers it a failure, and he's using JQuery which doesn't consider it a failure.  Who wins? Well the author should win, cause it's his application.  If the tool (JQuery) doesn't provide this ability, you'll probably need to do the check for the element yourself.

Comment: Possible duplication of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3709604/why-doesnt-jquery-bomb-if-your-selector-object-is-invalid

Answer (score 1):

If it was an ajax call, you can designate an error function to be called.  But without seeing any code, I am afraid the old crystal ball tends to overheat and get fogged up.